# Regex to match more than one word

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application containing a form field called 'First/last name'.  I need to add some basic validation to ensure people enter at least two words.  It doesn't need to be totally comprehensive in checking word length etc, we essentially just need to prevent people from entering just their first name which is what's happening currently.  I don't want to limit to just alphabetic characters as some names include punctuation.  I just want to ensure that people have entered at least two words separated by a space.

I have the following regex currently:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^((\b[a-zA-Z]{2,40}\b)\s*){2,}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid first/last name")]
```

This works to an extent (it checks for 2 words) but it's invalid if punctuation is entered, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Could anyone suggest how to modify the above so that it doesn't matter if punctuation is used in the words?  I'm not good with the regular expression syntax, hence asking here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want two words, so at least one space between them, and beyond that you want to allow everything else (e.g., punctuation). So keep it simple:

```
\w.*\s.*\w
```

Or if you *must* anchor it to start and end:

```
^.*\w.*\s.*\w.*$
```

These will match, for example, `D' Addario` (but not `D'Artagnan` by itself, since it counts as one word by the space criterion).

Comment: Will this be valid for more than 2 words?

Comment: Yes. It looks for two word characters and a space somewhere between them, but accepts _anything_ else between or around them-- including more words and spaces.

Comment: This regex allows a string to start with whitespace.

Comment: @stribizhev: Yes, it does allow a string to start with whitespace, and that's fine. Read the question. (Why would you want to reject a form because of stray space at the start, anyway?)

Comment: At any rate, this regex is less effecient than mine. Mine takes 19 steps on my sample string, and this one takes 59 steps. In regexhero.net, 213,758 (this one) iterations per second vs. 378,509 (mine). One should avoid using `.*` whenever possible.

Comment: @ stribizhev, This is about validating a name on a web form, for chrissake, it's not going to be gigabytes of data. There are times when efficiency is an issue, and this is not one of them. Use regexps that are easy to read and maintain, and match what you mean to match.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just:

```
@"\w\s\w"
```

`word` `white space` `word`

Comment: Will this be valid for more than 2 words?

Comment: This will not match `D. Knuth`, for example.

Comment: It won't work in the `RegularExpression` attribute as it requires a full string match.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to allow a sequence of non-whitespace characters followed by 1 or more sequences of whitespace characters followed by non-whitespace characters, you can use

```
^\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+)+\s*$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kA5bF5/4)

It won't accept just `First` or `First` .

Regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace
- `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespace symbols
- `(?:\s+\S+)+` - 1 or more sequences of ...

  - `\s+` - 1 or more whitespace sequences (remove `+` to allow only 1 whitespace between words)
  - `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespace symbols
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Will this be valid for more than 2 words?

Comment: Sure, because of the `+` quantifier that means *1 or **more** occurrences*. Follow the demo link in the answer to see a demo string containing several "words" split with a space. If you need to restrict to *1 space* between "words", [remove the `+` after `\s`](https://regex101.com/r/kA5bF5/2).

Comment: `david o'connor` returns as invalid, which isn't desirable.

Comment: `david o'connor` [is matched](https://regex101.com/r/kA5bF5/5) with and without trailing/leading spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use this regex for validation
'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+ {1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`'

Demo  http://rubular.com/r/YN8eFa1yFE